# How to get @PathParam and request body in same web-services?

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy

I am calling services and want to map the data from path param and from request body. web-services call is type of POST.
Problem here is if i use @Form then I am getting only path param
Here are the scenario.

```
 Case1 Url :- Response updateDepartment(@Form @Valid Department departmentObject)
```

I am getting path param value as departmentNumber, departmentSNumber and departmentName 
but not getting request body which contain addRequest[{ }] and removeRequest[{ }]

In case If i use only @Valid then

```
 Case 2 Url :- Response updateDepartment(@Valid Department departmentObject)
```

In this case, I am getting addRequest[{ }] and removeRequest[{ }] values.
but Object but now missing with departmentNumber, departmentSNumber and departmentName

Department.java

```
public class Department
    {

    @PathParam(DEPTNUMBER_PARAM)
    private String deptNumber;

    @PathParam(DEPT_S_PARAM)
    private String deptSNumber;


    @PathParam(DEPARTMENT_NAME)
    private String departmentName;

    private List<String> addRole;

    private List<String> removeRole;

    }
```

How to map both the values form @PathParam as well as request body values.
Here is the call

```
http://localhost:8080/myweb/departments/1234/4321/finance
{
    "addRole": [
            101,
             181
    ],
    "removeRole": [
            42,
             12
    ]
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use this:

```
Response updateDepartment(@Valid Department departmentObject, @PathParam("departmentNumber") String departmentNumber....)
```

What you want it will not work. I will try to explain.
First of all, I think you are using resteasy not JAX-RS  reference, correct?
In RestEasy for @Form annotation it said:

> This can be used as a value object for incoming/outgoing request/responses. You can re-use @*Param annotations on fields/methods of the parameter to unmarshall from the request or marshall to the response depending if you're using server-side JAX-RS or the Resteasy client framework

In your case, you use @PathParam on the fields of the parameter, that is  why was populated.

When you do not use @Form, whatever type you specify for the parameter it tries to match with **request body**, which, in your case contain only the two arrays and not the PathParam. It will not look into the path params for anything else, thus ignoring your annotation.

Comment: previously i have used same as above but validation of these properties sonar will flag the complexity, because of that i have changed into Object instead of path param